# How to upload photo to AWS S3 using the Fetch API?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, fetch-api

I am trying to upload a photo file to an S3 bucket using the Fetch API. I'm getting 400 Bad Request on the POST when trying to upload the photo. I am getting the presigned post url and the file details correctly but I believe the way I am formatting the formData is incorrect.

I'm using an html file input that uses onchange to run a javascript function handlePhoto.

The html is

```
<input type="file" onchange="handlePhoto()" id="file_input"/>
```

and javascript function is

```
function handlePhoto(){
    const file = document.getElementById('file_input').files[0]
    let formData = new FormData()
    fetch("/v1/photos/get_presigned_post/" , {
      method: "GET"
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(s3Result => {
      const { url, fields } = s3Result;
      Object.keys(s3Result.fields).forEach(key => {
        formData.append(key, s3Result.fields[key]);
      });
      formData.append('acl', 'public-read');
      formData.append('Content-Type', file.type);
      formData.append("file", file);

      fetch(url, {
        method: "POST",
        body: formData,
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
        }
      })
  });
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't use `mode: "no-cors"`. The S3 API supports CORS access

Comment: How do you know what the response is from your POST request? You don't have anything handling the response at all. If you can see the response status somehow, what is the response text?

Comment: I can see the request headers and payload using the Chrome Developer tools in my browser. The information is linked in these screenshots. Headers :https://i.imgur.com/FptTWU7.png  Request Payload: https://i.imgur.com/jaN61lo.png

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a presigned url you could use something like this:

```
interface UploadToS3Params {
  url: string;
  file: File;
}

export function uploadToS3(params: UploadToS3Params) {
  const { file, url } = params;
  return fetch(url, {
    body: file,
    mode: "cors",
    method: "PUT",
    // optional headers
    // headers: { "Content-Type": "text/plain" },
  });
}
```

Comment: How/where do you suggest that Content Type is set?

Comment: @FredrikWendt, I updated the code with how to set content type

Answer (score 0):

check the url  in s3Result, for me it was wrong link and it doesn't include my bucketname. url must be like this to work:

```
https://{bucket_name}.s3.amazonaws.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Your URL might not be right,
From the documentation, hostnames should look something like this.
"s3.Region.amazonaws.com".

These two links might help
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/RESTAPI.html
and,
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-HTTPPOSTForms.html

Answer (score -2):

You don't need to use a FormData, just pass the file with a content-type 'octet-stream'.

acl must be used when generating the presign URL.

```
fetch(url, {
                method: 'PUT',
                body: file,
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream' }
            })
```